# How to remotely run xcode bots

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, osx-server

There are mac osx server (slave) and another jenkins server (master). I would like to remotely order building and testing of my ios application on osx server from jenkins server.  I would like to use xcode bots on osx server but I don't know how to manage bots from terminal. How to do it ? Is it possible to use bots as a part of bigger continuous integration system, or I have to set up jenkins server on my osx server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can manage OSX bots without using the Xcode connected to your Xcode server.

Anyway Xcode server is still very limited and you wont be able to do what you can do with Jenkins with multiple steps (ie if you use Cocoapods or if you want to deploy something at the end of the build)

If you are using Jenkins on a master server I think the best thing to do is to use your Mac server as slave via SSH to allow your Jenkins to build your iOS projects on it.

Comment: So I am able to build iOS project on slave OSX machine remotely from Jenkins server ? Don't I have to set up jenkins on osx machine ?

Comment: you only need to setup your OSX slave to be able to build xcode projects (install Xcode + xcodebuild command line tools) and allow your main jenkins server to connect to this machine using SSH.

Answer (score 3):

You can now manage and edit bots from Xcode 9 by logging in to

`Xcode Preferences > Accounts > + button`

[image]

then go to Report Navigator to see your server

[image]

If you just want to integrate or see the status, you can actually access it from the browser. /xcode

example: https://XX.XX.XX.XX/xcode

here's a good reference: https://medium.com/xcblog/xcode9-xcode-server-comprehensive-ios-continuous-integration-3613a7973b48